# Adding messages to or below input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form that has a series of inputs. Input 1 changes the options for Input 2. Input 2 is blank and until input one is filled, I need to make it so that if the user clicks on input 2 to try to fill out first a message tells them to please select from input 1 first.

I have jQuery doing an alert box currently but how can I have the message show up in the input or right below it?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon_guy/pen/WXgZQw

HTML:

```
<form>
  Input-1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="first" id="one"><br>
  Input-2:<br>
  <input type="text" name="second" id="two" >
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#two" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Please enter Input 1 First" );
});
```

Comment: why not `disabled` the input 2 .. And when Input 1 is properly filled out do a `$( "#input_2" ).prop( "disabled", false );`  ?

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense, and be a better user experience, to only enable input 2 once input 1 has received a value. You can do that using the `input` event, like this:

```js
$('#one').on('input', function() {
  $('#two').prop('disabled', this.value.trim() == '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Input-1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="first" id="one"><br>
  Input-2:<br>
  <input type="text" name="second" id="two" disabled="disabled">
</form>
```

Comment: This method seems to be much more semantically and logically valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically insert text/html via **[after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)** if the criteria isn't met. Though a more ideal approach would be to use `focus` over `click` in this case:

```js
$( '#two' ).on('focus', function() {
  if (!$('#one').val().length) {
    $('#two').after('<p>Please enter Input 1 First</p>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Input-1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="first" id="one"><br>
  Input-2:<br>
  <input type="text" name="second" id="two" >
  <p class="warning"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add it *inside* the first input box (as a placeholder):

```js
$("#two").click(function() {
  if ($("#one").val() == "") {
    $("#one").attr("placeholder", "Please enter Input 1 First");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Input-1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="first" id="one"><br> Input-2:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="second" id="two">
</form>
```

To add it as a message below the inputs:

```js
$("#two").click(function() {
  if ($("#one").val() == "") {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.id = "newDiv";
    newDiv.innerText = "Please enter Input 1 First";
    $("form").append(newDiv, $("#two").next());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  Input-1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="first" id="one"><br> Input-2:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="second" id="two">
</form>
```

The `if` statement will cause the message to only display if the first input box has no value:

```
if ($("#one").val() == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach it to the parent.

You can evaluate the first input field to see if it is empty. There are a number of things you can do to remove the appended div.

```
$( "#two" ).click(function() {
  if($("#one").val("")){
   $(this).parent().append("<div>Please enter Input 1  First</div>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that this will always fire, regardless of whether `#one` has been given a value or not.

Comment: True; just check if #one is empty